# Prevent race conditions in sending data to endpoint and storing in database in Django REST API

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, race-condition

I am writing a web application in Django REST API where I have an endpoint that accepts POST requests:

https://website.com/api/receive-data

with the following body:

```
{
'value': 1,
}
```

And my code:

```
# models.py

class MyModelA(models.Model):
status = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class MyModelB(models.Model):
value = models.IntegerField()
model_a_pk = models.IntegerField()

# views.py

class ModelBRecordData(APIView):
def post(self, request, format=None):
    serialzier = ModelBSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
      model_b = MyModelB.objects.create(value=value, model_a_pk=serializer.data.get('model_a_pk'))
      model_b.save()
      model_bs = MyModelB.objects.filter().count()
      if model_bs > 100000:
          model_a = MyModelA.objects.filter(pk=serializer.data.get('model_a_pk')).first()
          model_a.status = True
          model_a.save()
```

The problem here is that I may be receiving 1000 endpoint requests at the same time. This will get this app into race conditions so more than a 100,000 records may be created while model_a is still being updated.

How do I prevent this kind of race condition in an app like this?

Answer (score 0):

You should set a DB lock on model_a you're going to update, but a lock is released when DB transaction finishes (by default each create/update DB query is a separate small transaction) so you need to manually create a DB transaction within which you should perform all your DB updates:

```py
from django.db import transaction

class ModelBRecordData(APIView):
def post(self, request, format=None):
  with transaction.atomic(): # start a DB transaction manually
    serialzier = ModelBSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
      # select model_a for update, and by doing it you set a lock on it, so all
      # parallel requests that also try to select it for update
      # will wait until the lock is released
      model_a = MyModelA.objects.select_for_update().get(pk=serializer.data.get('model_a_pk'))
      model_b = MyModelB.objects.create(value=value, model_a_pk=serializer.data.get('model_a_pk'))
      model_bs = MyModelB.objects.filter().count()
      if model_bs > 100000:
        model_a.status = True
        model_a.save()
```

More info about transactions in django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/transactions/

And about `select_for_update` method: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update